# Cypress.io: function to click random element AND get its text

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am currently working with Cypress and have created a function that randomly clicks an element from a list. I am trying to also get the text from that same function for future assertions. The problem is I am unable to return the text properly. The code I currently have is:

```
    export function selectRandomFromList(listLocator, elementLocator) {
    cy.get(listLocator).within(() => {
       let numberOfElements = Cypress.$(listLocator + ' ' + elementLocator).length
       let selected = Cypress._.random(0, numberOfElements - 1)
        cy.get(elementLocator).eq(selected).then(($text) => {
                const text = $text.text()
                return text
        }).click()
    })
  }
```

I was hoping that I could then in my test run this function, do the click and then store the returned text in a variable for future checking. What am I doing wrong? Also tried some other stuff with promises and such, when the code was saying I am trying to mix sync and async..

Forgot to add. This is in the support file and I want to use the `text` variable in the test file. Something like this:

```
var text = function.selectRandomFromList('[class*=***]', 'li ul li button')
```

After which I should have the text of the clicked button in `text`.

Comment: You shouldn't return values from Cypress commands, instead try to assign the value to an [alias](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values) and retrieve it later.

Answer (score 4):

Cypress commands work the same way as Promises. You need to return a Promise when inside a `then()` callback. See doc [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html#Yields).

You may use `cy.wrap($text).invoke('text')` inside your `then()` callback instead of returning a string. But then, your `click()` would not work because your `then()` would yield a text value that cannot be clicked.

I suggest not using the `within()` and working directly with the elements. You'll end up with the same result, but with less complexity. I use the `within()` command when I need to perform several actions on several elements within a div container for example.

You can perform what you need with default commands instead of a function:

```
let mixLocator = listLocator + ' ' + elementLocator;
cy.get(mixLocator).its('length').then(elementCount => {
    let selected = Cypress._.random(elementCount - 1); // lower = 0 is default
    cy.get(mixLocator).eq(selected).click().invoke('text').as('selectedText'); // saving the text as an alias to be used later
});
```

Here, the `invoke('text')` should still work even if it is after the `click()`, but it is impossible to do the opposite `invoke('text').click()` because the `invoke('text')` command yields a string. If it doesn't, call it once to get the text and again to click it:

```
cy.get(mixLocator).eq(selected).invoke('text').as('selectedText');
cy.get(mixLocator).eq(selected).click();
```

or:

```
cy.get(mixLocator).eq(selected).then(selectedElement => {
    cy.wrap(selectedElement).invoke('text').as('selectedText');
    cy.wrap(selectedElement).click();
});
```

You may then use your saved [alias](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as.html#Syntax) later:

```
cy.get('@selectedText').then(selectedText => {
    // use selectedText here
});
```

---

I often prefer to chose random elements in our tests to have a better coverage. I came up with a [custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax):

commands.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('any', { prevSubject: 'element' }, (subject, size = 1) => {
  cy.wrap(subject).then(elementList => {
    elementList = (elementList.jquery) ? elementList.get() : elementList;
    elementList = Cypress._.sampleSize(elementList, size);
    elementList = (elementList.length > 1) ? elementList : elementList[0];
    cy.wrap(elementList);
  });
});
```

I use it like this:

```
cy.get(elementLocator).any().click();
```

or

```
cy.get(elementLocator).any(5).each(randomElement => {
    cy.wrap(randomElement).click();
});
```

Comment: Very good comment but I had forgotten to add some extra detail on how I want to use this. Kinda baffles the mind how hard this basic thing is in Cypress :(

Comment: for me it says Cypress_.sampleSize command not found, any idea why?

Comment: I forgot a dot after Cypress. It should be `Cypress._.sampleSize`. I fixed it in my answer.